# Open neutral wire at the breaker panel

Tags: electrical, wiring, neutral

We just moved into our house and the previous owner remodeled the master bathroom. There is a GFCI outlet in the master bathroom and it was ungrounded and I took it out and discovered that the ground wire was wired in with the neutral wire.

With my multimeter I measured 125.9V from hot to ground (this is good), 4.92V from hot to neutral (it should be around 120V), and 123.8V from neutral to ground (it should be around 0). I think these readings indicate an open neutral between the GFCI and the breaker panel.

This was a remodel job, and the GFCI wasn't there before the remodeling, and no new outlets were added between the master bathroom and the garage, which is where the breaker panel is located. There is a utility room between the master bathroom and the garage and there is nothing new in the utility room; no new outlets, and everything in there works when the two master bathroom breakers are turned off. There are no new outlets in the garage, either. I'm praying that there is not a disconnected neutral wire in the walls or ceiling.

And so my question is, "How do I check for the open neutral in the breaker panel? Do I look for a loose white wire or screw at the 2 master bathroom breaker switches? Do I measure with my multimeter? Where do I put the red and black probes? Would I get the same reading as I did at the GFCI outlet? Should I leave the power on? Is that safe as long as I don't touch  the wires?"

Comment: Are your wires in cables(all wires together covered in plastic) or conduit (Separate wires in tubes)?  Would turn off main breaker(for safety) and remove the cover.  Find the breakers for the problem circuit/s and find where the black(or red) wire enters the panel, should be a white wire with it.  Check connections of white wire, then you probably need to check the whole circuit at outlets/lights/ and switches for broken neutral connection.

Comment: Yes, all the wires are in sheathing and are non-metallic (NM-B).  I'll turn off the main breaker, etc.

Comment: I take it the other outlets in the house test correct?  My initial guess is that there's an issue with a shared neutral that someone was having trouble resolving.  Maybe installed a GFCI on the bathroom circuit that was shared on the same neutral with that bedroom outlet, and everytime someone used that outlet, it tripped the bathroom gfci.  Does the breaker that turns off the bedroom outlet have a wire that leads to a cable with three conductors (a red, black, and white)?

Comment: I'm not able to check the breaker panel as of yet but  when I do I'll see if the breaker that turns off the bedroom outlet has a wire that leads to a cable with three conductors (a red, black, and white).

Comment: @DavidWatson - Could you take a picture while you're there - with the cover off?

Comment: if the main breaker is off is it safe to touch the wires coming into and out of the breakers and the buses with the panel off?  I see videos of people testing wires on the breaker box with a multimeter. Can I check the wires for looseness by hand with the main off and then turn the main on and test with a multimeter without touching anything with my hands?  I know that the power company still has the power on so if the main is off is it safe to touch components and wires that are down below the main switch?

Comment: Yes, it would be great to take a picture and we could discuss exactly what's what in the panel.

Comment: @DavidWatson -- the wires going into the main breaker will still be live, even with the main breaker off

Comment: Questions: 1. How do electricians protect themselves?  2. With the main off, if I don't touch the big wires coming in from the utility or the big lugs I won't get shocked, but I can touch the breaker wires/buses,  right? 3. With the main on, is it safe to check for voltage on the breaker wires and buses with my multimeter? 4. With the main off, is it good to test for voltage with the multimeter before touching the breaker wires/buses?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this is a simple problem that was not handled correctly by the last person who worked on that GFCI outlet.

If the GFCI is the only outlet on its circuit, then you might have a loose wire in the panelboard.  However, if there is any other outlet (receptacle, light, appliance) on the same circuit, it will be necessary to first determine if the other outlets have the same problem or not by testing all of them with the multimeter.

So the first step is to check which circuit breaker turns off the hot wire to the GFCI.

Second, check which other lights and receptacles stop working when that circuit breaker is off.

Third, turn the circuit back on and check the hot-to-neutral voltage at every outlet.

Fourth, if you find some outlets are working and some are not, you will likely need to open up every outlet on that circuit and look for loose neutral wires.  Likewise, if none of the outlets are correct, you might need to figure out which outlet has the homerun cable and figure out which end of that cable (outlet or panelboard) isn't connected to the neutral bus.

Fifth, you indicated "123.8V from neutral to ground" at the GFCI.  This could mean something else on the circuit was turned on and connected to the same open neutral when you measured the GFCI.

If you remove the panelboard cover for any reason: Wear gloves, wear safety glasses, and don't touch anything you haven't verified as 0 V to ground.

Additionally, avoid using any outlet that reads less than 110 V hot to neutral.  The extra voltage naturally wants to go anywhere it can, creating unsafe conditions for fires and personnel.

Comment: There are two 20 amp circuits that serve the master bath, and in addition to the GFCI there is a NuHeat  SOLO floor  heater and a towel rack warmer that looks hard wired and never worked.  After I put the ground wire in its place on the GFCI and turned on the power the NuHeat didn't come on anymore and neither did the electric toilet. Wouldn't that indicate they're on the same circuit? The NuHeat doesn't have a ground wire; grounding is done via the grounding wire in the heating apparatus. I don't know which components are on which of the 2 breakers that serve the master bath.

Comment: Don't panic.  Just turn off one of the two circuits.  Check the hot wire at the GFCI.  If still hot, try switching off the other circuit.  If still hot after that, you need to keep looking for the correct switch.  If you can do the same with your bathroom appliances that might help.  And you will need to follow the other steps from my answer if you want to diagnose this by yourself.  It's better to check the outlet connections before assuming the problem is in a service panel.

Comment: I tested the GCFI outlet and the towel warmer outlet; they only have the house wires in them now. Black, white, and ground are all continuous between these two outlets and I still have 0V hot to neutral and 120V hot to ground in both of them. The only outlet left in the bathroom is the floor heater panel. I read that if there is continuity between neutral and ground on a receptacle the problem (i.e. disconnected neutral) is in that receptacle or the one next to it.  Do you agree? The floor heater has the ground in the heating apparatus and it may be on a different breaker.  What next?

Comment: Checking continuity is just going to slow you down.  If you can turn off the circuit and determine which outlets are no longer hot then you will be closer to finding the homerun cable for testing.  If the GFCI is at the far end of the circuit and the towel warmer is somewhere in the middle, then is there another outlet involved?  Have you determined that all of the neutral wires in that circuit are abnormal?

Comment: Both breakers are off. There are  3 outlets in the bathroom.  The GFCI has no outgoing wires, and the towel warmer outlet has no outgoing wires. How can that be?  They are on the same breaker and are both at the end of the circuit and the towel warmer has the same abnormal voltage as the GFCI outlet. The 3rd outlet has a screen on it and  is for the floor heater and it turned off when I rewired the GCFI correctly.  It's off now when both breakers  are on.  I took the screen off; there are 2 red wires and 2 black wires to the back of the panel that I can't pull  out.

Comment: Both breakers are single pole breakers.  I assume the black wires are hot and the red wires are neutral. The heater can be  either 240V or 120V so it must be 120V. There is another big wad of light brown wires in the electrical box that I assume go to the heating elements under the floor.  I need to pull all the wires out of the box and test the voltage on the incoming wires. The red and black wires and the brown wires must be pigtailed to the incoming wires. I was afraid to pull all the wires out of the box to expose the incoming wires because they don't budge but I'll have to do it.

Comment: I don't think that the  floor heater outlet feeds the GFCI  outlet because I think the floor heater is on the 2nd breaker.   But why would the floor heater go out when I rewired the GFCI outlet correctly if the floor heater outlet is on the 2nd breaker? If all 3 outlets are on the same breaker what's the use of the 2nd breaker?

Comment: You're confusing hot and neutral at this point.  With a bad neutral, nothing will work regardless of the circuit breaker being on or off.  The breaker only controls the hot wire, and yes you might need to separate the heater wires to test them.  So after correcting the GFCI connections you can't assume to know which circuit is involved just because some other things stopped working or have bad neutrals.  This is a separate issue from tracing the hot wire for each circuit.

Comment: If the GFCI and towel warmer both have hot wires from the same circuit breaker, then they are connected at some point, possibly involving the bathroom lights or another room.

Comment: I pulled the wires out of the box behind the NuHeat panel and there were separate pigtails w/multiple wires for white, black, and neutral. I took off all the wire nuts and turned on the breaker the other 2 circuits are on and the wires were hot and had good voltage readings. So all 3 outlets are on the same breaker and the other breaker isn't used. There must be a junction box(es)  behind the wall upstream. I measured the voltage on the toilet GFCI and got good readings. Maybe the white pigtail wasn't making a good connection. I'll use new pigtails and push it all back in and see if it works.

Comment: Sounds like good progress.  The info just isn't detailed enough for me to help.  Do you want to add some photos of what you've found at the three outlets?

Comment: [This](https://photos.google.com/photo/AF1QipOGq2pPioRZuWDuaA6Rx-G7dy5jzyirvGhsoWg) is a photo of the  NuHeat outlet. The open neutral was caused by a loose connection in the pigtail for the white wires.  This outlet is the only one that's not working now.  I pushed all the wires back in and screwed in the panel and the screen is still blank. Maybe the black wire to the NuHeat panel came loose in the pigtail when I pushed it all back into the box.  Do you know how I can troubleshoot this issue? This is a [NuHeat Solo](https://www.nuheat.com/virtual-thermostats/solo/) panel.

Comment: The photo link does not work.  Try attaching a photo to your original question.  Rather than pushing all the wires back in, try to probe the open end of the wire nuts to verify the voltage, then turn on the heater.  If you need to jiggle or tighten the nuts it can be done carefully.  Wire nuts need to be hand tight to the point where the wires start twisting outside the nut.  I would leave all of the outlets open until you've fully resolved the issue, to allow for continued troubleshooting.